# Downloading Files (JPG and PDF) from server - laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I am able to upload jpg and pdf to my server (database). Now, I want to be able to download it when I click on the file itself in my view as shown below.

When I click on the file, it routes me to the download page and says page cannot be found and the file is not downloaded

What am I not doing right?

**Controller**

```
   public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        $storeFiles = new File;

        $uniqueFileName = uniqid() . Input::file('upload_file')->getClientOriginalName() . '.' . Input::file('upload_file')->getClientOriginalExtension();

        Input::file('upload_file')->move(public_path('/public/files') . $uniqueFileName);

        $storeFiles->path = $uniqueFileName;
        $storeFiles->description = Input::get('description');
        $storeFiles->save();
        return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'File uploaded successfully.');
    }





 public function download($filename)
    {
    $file_path = public_path('/public/files'). $filename;
    if (file_exists($file_path))
    {
        // Send Download
        return Response::download($file_path, $filename, [
            'Content-Length: '. filesize($file_path)
        ]);
    }
    else
    {
        // Error
        exit('Requested file does not exist on our server!');
    }

    }
```

**Routes**

```
   Route::get('/course/download/{{file?}}', 'FileController@download')->name('course.download');
```

**View**

```
      <td><a  href="{{ URL::to( '/course/download/' . $file->path)  }}">{{$file->path}}</a></td>
```

Comment: Just an FYI, `public_path` doesn't point to `app/storage` it points to app/public. Also, can you confirm that the files are definitely there?

Comment: @RossWilson, edited..the comment is not suppose to be there. My files are actually in my public folder

Comment: Ah fair enough, I thought that might be the case. Can you confirm that the files are actually there though?

Comment: @RossWilson, my files are there